# Spring Data MongoDB, Searching by long value

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an object stored in mongo which looks like below (this is how it is shown in RoboMongo, when I view the document):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e579c8674f69d1c1451f3ae"),
    ...
    "timestamp": NumberLong(1582800002779),
    ...
    "_class": "regular"
}
```

The object I store is defined like this:

```
public class MyObjectModel {
    @Id
    @Field(value = ID_FIELD_NAME)
    private String id;
    @Field(value = TIMESTAMP_FIELD_NAME)
    private Long timestamp;
...
}
```

My intension is to get the list of objects within the timeframe. 
This is how I create query with spring data mongo db:

```
    public List<Criteria> generateAllCriteria() {
        List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional.ofNullable(searchCriteria.getFromTimestamp()).map(ts -> criteriaList.add(generateFromTimestampCriteria(ts)));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchCriteria.getToTimestamp()).map(ts -> criteriaList.add(generateToTimestampCriteria(ts)));
        return criteriaList;
    }

    private Criteria generateFromTimestampCriteria(Long fromTimestamp) {
        Criteria critFromTimestamp = Criteria.where(TIMESTAMP_FIELD_NAME).gte(fromTimestamp);
        log.debug("From Timestamp criteria {}", critFromTimestamp.getCriteriaObject().toJson());
        return critFromTimestamp;
    }

    private Criteria generateToTimestampCriteria(Long toTimestamp) {
        Criteria critToTimestamp = Criteria.where(TIMESTAMP_FIELD_NAME).lt(toTimestamp);
        log.debug("To Timestamp criteria {}", critToTimestamp.getCriteriaObject().toJson());
        return critToTimestamp;
    }
...
    List<Criteria> criteriaList = generateAllCriteria();

    Criteria finalCriteria = new Criteria();
    finalCriteria = finalCriteria.andOperator(criteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[criteriaList.size()]));
    log.debug("Final criteria {}", finalCriteria);
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(finalCriteria);

    List<MyObjectModel> myObjects = mongoTemplate.find(query, MyObjectModel.class);
```

The queries when I display them they are the following:

```
From Timestamp criteria { "timestamp" : { "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "1582714365857" } } }
To Timestamp criteria { "timestamp" : { "$lt" : { "$numberLong" : "1582887165858" } } }
```

And the final query criteria seems to be this:

```
o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { "$and" : [{ "timestamp" : { "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "1582714365857" } } }, { "timestamp" : { "$lt" : { "$numberLong" : "1582887165858" } } }] } fields: Document{{}} for class: class mypackage.model.MyObjectModel in collection: myObjectModel
```

From the first glance it seems OK, but when I run it against Mongo manually it does not return any records, which in my opinion means that it is somehow incorrect. 
Here is what exactly I run on Mongo:

```
db.getCollection('my-collection').find({ "$and" : [{ "timestamp" : { "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "1582707873806" } } }, { "timestamp" : { "$lt" : { "$numberLong" : "1582887165858" } } }] })
```

And it obviously does not return any records. But when I modify the query and get rid of $numberLong:

```
db.getCollection('my-collection').find({ "$and" : [{ "timestamp" : { "$gte" : 1582707873806 } }, { "timestamp" : { "$lt" : 1582887165858 } }] })
```

it works like a charm.

Can someone enlighten me and explain what I am doing wrong? How should it be done in correct way?
How to make spring data mongo to create proper query?

Needless to say that string and ints are working perfectly fine. It is only about **LONG**s.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Does your Spring-Data MongoDB query run and return the expected results?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. When I run my app spring data mongodb query as stated above does not return any entries. When I run query from robomongo it does return results only if I provide value. when I seach by timestamp:...{$numberlong: "aNumber"} it does not return anything.

Comment: in fact when called from robomongo instead of $numberLong one shall use NumberLong() function.Then it works fine. I learned that when investigating my problem.

Comment: Does this approach worked? I am also facing the same issue of numberlong being added to the query parameter and returining absolutely no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand:

- from/to are the only parameters in query
- both can be null

and assuming your model is:

```
public class Regular {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field
  private Long timestamp;
}
```

Then possible solution (IMHO much shorter) is:

```
// exists(true) is a "hack" to return the elements in case both from/to are null
public List<Regular> find(Long from, Long to) {

  var criteria = where("timestamp").exists(true);
  if(from != null) {
    criteria.gte(from);
  }
  if(to != null) {
    criteria.lte(to);
  }

  return mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(criteria), Regular.class);
}
```

PS. I have checked it with **Spring Boot 2.2.4** and **Mongo 3.6**.

PS2. Still you can handle the case when from/to are both null by extra if condition and then remove **exists(true)**.

Comment: would you be so kind and provide the query which mongo template builds? Thank you. I did the same as you and still not getting any data.

Comment: The result of `Query.query(criteria).toString()` is:
`Query: { "timestamp" : { "$exists" : true, "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "10"}, "$lte" : { "$numberLong" : "20"}}}, Fields: {}, Sort: {}`

Comment: This is what I am getting as well... and for some reason it does not work. I will revisit this piece this week and will get back if this helped or what I had to do. Thanks

Comment: Here is the thing, I have made a mistake in the code above. That thing works fine. I had a class that extends Regular and the collection was on that class. In mongo template I wanted to get only those attributes which fit Regular class. so in fact I incorrectly called find method on mongoTemplate. Sorry for this mistake. And indeed my code snippet above was not exactly what I had in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this same problem that i was facing.
I just created a custom read Converter which maps DATE value to long value when i fetch data from the database.
Here is a link for the reference i took
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@singh.chhaya52/custom-converters-for-incompatible-mongodb-datatypes-in-spring-9ddf23cdc2c)